# Find center of a fiducial marker

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality, orb

I need to track four points on a series of photos of a moving object. 
At first, I tried markers that looked like four squares of a chessboard (2 white and 2 black) and ORB detector:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('D:/workspace_Rita/Tag5.jpg',0)

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# find the keypoints with ORB
kp = orb.detect(img,None)
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)

img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,None,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()
```

Image: http://postimg.org/image/52phl54rz/

Аlong with the required points (centers of the markers), I got a lot of noise, so I decided to change chessboard markers to fiducial ones, drawn in ARTag style. Moreover, these markers would help identify the points, if the object rotates. Now, with the same Python code, I get:

Image: http://postimg.org/image/f58zzrkl5/

Still I have noise points detected, and I don't see an easy way to extract the coordinates of the markers centers from the keypoints mass.
I think, I need either to adjust the sensitivity of the detector (maybe, do some pre-filtering of the image), or find another algorithm.

I would appreciate ideas and examples, which detectors or algorithms I could use to track fiducial markers centers in the easiest way, preferring Python language and Open CV.

Comment: One option is to use more robust detectors, another option is to postprocess (filter) the detection. You could apply a postprocessing to your detected points knowing that your points should appear in groups of 4 adjacent centers in square form. You can formulate this as an optimization problem an try to get the best set of points, or you could use something lke [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) to randomly try groups of 4 points and compute their distances and keep the best ones. [RANSAC demo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RANSAC_LINIE_Animiert.gif)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try to use RANSAC.
Do you know more robust detectors?

Comment: It seems I was wrong thinking that there must be very well-developed libraries with all sorts of filters and stabilizers for such useful items as fiducial markers(

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to detect. you could *train* a detector or try using [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html). Calibration routines usually use checkboard patterns, have a look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html).

Comment: Have a look here: https://infi.nl/nieuws/marker-detection-for-augmented-reality-applications/

Comment: I have already tried Template Matching: it could work well, but it requires copmplex  (in my opinion) geometric transformations: a marker in the image may look like a parallelogram or trapezoid of different sizes, for matching with a template it will have to be transformed into a square of a given size.
I found a detector that could solve my problem: [link](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/imager/tr/2010/Atcheson_VMV2010_CALTag/  "CALTag") , but there is some error in the provided pattern generating code which I can't identify. Though it works great with the test pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you were too quick to detect the markers. Here is how to do it:

1. Denoising (optional) with a median filter
2. Simple thresholding to detect the bright/white surfaces
3. Keep the biggest one in the image center (the white panel). This can be fine-tuned by adding a hough filter in order to find parallel lines (the panel/rectangle borders).
4. New thresholding in order to detect the dark areas in the previous result.
5. Connected component labeling to separate the dark zones. If they touch each other.
6. Centroid of each zone, else ultimate eroded if the zones touche each other.